# Issue with clEnqueueReadBuffer Function in OpenCL - in an Array Sum Sample

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl

everyone,
   I'm a beginner on OpenCL and I wrote some simple code in C which sums two arrays. Here is part of the code:

```
// Create Kernel.

cl_kernel kernelSum = clCreateKernel( myProgram, "sum", &error );


// Set Input Array.

size_t arraySize = 1000;

char* a = ( char* ) malloc( sizeof( char ) * arraySize );
char* b = ( char* ) malloc( sizeof( char ) * arraySize );
char* c = ( char* ) malloc( sizeof( char ) * arraySize );

for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i += 1)
{
    a[ i ] = 1;
    b[ i ] = 2;
    c[ i ] = -1;
}


// Set Buffers.

cl_mem a_buffer = clCreateBuffer(
    myContext,
    CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
    arraySize * sizeof( char ), a,
    &error );

cl_mem b_buffer = clCreateBuffer(
    myContext,
    CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
    arraySize * sizeof( char ), b,
    &error );

cl_mem c_buffer = clCreateBuffer(
    myContext,
    CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
    arraySize * sizeof( char ), NULL,
    &error );

printf( "Buffers created.\n" );


// Setting Kernel Arguments.

error = clSetKernelArg( kernelSum, 0, sizeof( cl_mem ), &a_buffer );

error |= clSetKernelArg( kernelSum, 1, sizeof( cl_mem ), &b_buffer );

error |= clSetKernelArg( kernelSum, 2, sizeof( cl_mem ), &c_buffer );

printf( "Arguments Set.\n" );


// Enqueue kernels to execute.

cl_event event;

size_t globalWorkOffset = 0;

size_t globalWorkSize[ 1 ] = { arraySize };

size_t localWorkSize[ 1 ] = { 1 };

clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(
    myCommandQueue,
    kernelSum,
    1,                  // work_dim
    0,              // global work offset
    globalWorkSize,
    localWorkSize,              // local work offset
    0, NULL,
    &event
    );

printf( "Kernel Enqueued.\n" );

error = clEnqueueReadBuffer(
    myCommandQueue,
    c_buffer,
    CL_TRUE,                        // blocking option
    ( size_t ) 0, arraySize * sizeof( char ),   // offset, data_size
    c,                              // host_ptr
    0, NULL,
    &event );

if ( error != CL_SUCCESS )
{
    printf( "Buffer Reading Back Failed.\n" );
    exit( 1 );
}
```

However, I got incorrect result : all the numbers in "c" array are zeros. I thought it has something to do with clEnqueueReadBuffer, or perhaps not. Any ideas about this issue? Expecting your suggestions! :-)

Comment: The problem is probably somewhere earlier than call to `clEnqueueReadBuffer`. To get an idea check `error` variable every time you issue a command.

Comment: You are right. After checking I found the error originated from failure of kernel creation. The returned error number of "clCreateKernelsInProgram" matches CL_INVALID_KERNEL, and Here is my kernel : __kernel void sum( __global const char *a, __global const char *b, __global char *c ){int tid = get_global_id( 0 );c[ tid ] = a[ tid ] + b[ tid ];}    When I call "clCreateKernelsInProgram( myProgram, NULL, NULL, &numbers)", the "number" became 0! I can't tell where I've mishandled.

Comment: Are you calling both `clCreateKernel` and `clCreateKernelsInProgram`? Why?

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't explain this. I did some modification after resorting to StackOverflow. I found the returned value of clEnqueueNDRangeKernel matched CL_INVALID_KERNEL. I originally used clCreateKernel and after I found failure of kernel enqueue the clCreateKernelsInProgram was added to query total number of available kernels then I found the number is zero, which means "no available kernel". Based on this I realized that the real cause of this is stemmed from an earlier API call.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `clEnqueueReadBuffer` will not wait for the kernel to finish. It will most likely execute simultaneously with the kernel. Change the call to:

```
error = clEnqueueReadBuffer(
    myCommandQueue,
    c_buffer,
    CL_TRUE,                        // blocking option
    ( size_t ) 0, arraySize * sizeof( char ),   // offset, data_size
    c,                              // host_ptr
    1, &event,
    NULL );
```

This will cause `clEnqueueReadBuffer` to wait for the kernel event to finish before starting to read the buffer.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion is right, but I think my command queue with default properties will execute commands in sequence, since I didn't specify CL_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, I always use this flag so I'm used to programs behaving this way.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone. All your suggestions are really helpful. It's with your help I finally found what I've done wrong : 
   clBuildProgram( myProgram, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, &error );
This is my original code.
The official definition of this function is :
cl_int clBuildProgram(cl_program program,
cl_uint num_devices,
const cl_device_id *device_list,
const char *options,
void (CL_CALLBACK *pfn_notify)
(cl_program program,
void *user_data),
void *user_data)
I found I set the last of the argument list as "&error"; I got this function mixed with some others whose argument list usually ends with an error number. Here, I should have call it like this:
clBuildProgram( myProgram, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, NULL );
The last one set to NULL. Then the program run correctly.

Thank you all very much! :-)